# Function to transfer values in dictionary Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to make a function for an assignment that will transfer money from a checking to a savings account,.   We were given this initial code:

```
class portfolio:

    def __init__(self):
        self.checking = {}
        self.saving = {}
        self.credit = {}
        self.stock = {}
```

And then the start of this code to make the function to transfer the money:

```
def invest_in_savings_account(self, account_id_savings, amount, account_id_checking):
```

I've tried numerous code, but none will pass the test cases.   Can someone explain to me why this won't work?

```
def invest_in_savings_account(self, account_id_savings, amount, account_id_checking):
    try:
       self.checking[account_id_checking] -= amount
       self.saving[account_id_savings] += amount
    except:
          return None
```

If the account id doesn't exist or if there are no funds in the checking account, the function is to do nothing.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  I've worked on this all day and haven't been able to solve it.

This is the test case it must pass:

```
myportfolio.invest_in_savings_account('discover_saving_3785', 1000, 'discover_7732')
if (myportfolio.saving == {'chase_saving_4444': 0, 'discover_saving_3785':1000}) and (myportfolio.checking == {'chase_6688': 100, 'discover_7732':5500}):
    print('Pass')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

Comment: your the biggest mistake is `except: return None`. You may get error and you don't even know it and you can't see error message which could help you to resolve problem. You should at least use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`. OR remove `try/except` for some time till you resolve problem.

Comment: as for me problem is that all dictionaries are empty - there is no `self.checking[account_id_checking]` and `self.saving[account_id_savings]` in dictionaries so you can't add/substract value to/from not-existing account. You should first create accounts, put some money and then you can transfer. But you still would have to check if there is enough money to transfer - if you don't want to make debit.

Comment: @furas is right. All dictionnaries are empty. We need to know how `checking` and `saving` look like....

Comment: This is a question as part of a larger assignment where we had to make the codes for adding accounts and depositing money prior.  Our codes have to be generic because the professor will then input the information.  I added the test case to the initial post.

Comment: Either use a `defaultdict` or check if the key already exists.

Comment: your test case will always fail if you have empty dictionares. It needs some other actions (or tests) which will fill dictionares before you will test transfer. I expect that professor will test your function using dictionares with some values. To pass this test you need accounts `chase_saving_4444`, `discover_saving_3785`, `chase_6688` with 0 and account `discover_7732` with  6500 .You should create dictionares with these values and then run this test to pass. You can also create on your own other tests to test other situations - like transfering from empty or not existing account.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things going on here, most simple first, always start a class with a capital letter, it isn't necessary but it's good practice:

```
def class Portfolio:
```

After reading your comments it appears you need this to work without money in the accounts. You can write the code but you won't be able to test it, so really you need to make functions to create accounts and to add / remove money. If you haven't created any accounts your dictionaries will always come back empty. If you don't put money into them then the function will never do anything, I'm confused as to how you would go about moving something that doesn't exist.

Try something like this:

```
def create_checking_account(self,account_id):
    self.checking[account_id] = None

def add_funds_checking(self,account_id,amount):
    self.checking[account_id] += amount

def invest_in_savings(self, account_id_savings, amount, account_id_checking):

    if self.checking[account_id_checking] >= amount:
        self.checking[account_id_checking] -= amount
        self.savings[account_id_savings] += amount
    else:
        print('error')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer-  the problem is when I add in values to the accounts to move then it won't pass the tests.  There are several test cases with different amounts.  So you're saying that there isn't a way to do this generically?  I have to put money into the accounts for the function to work?

Comment: If you're creating a function to move money from one account to another how can it work if there is no money in any account? You can put money in and then move it but if there isn't anything to move then you're not going to be able to move it. Yes you can write the code correctly without the money there but you won't be able to test it. You will always get an empty dictionary as that is all you have.

Comment: Oh I see!  That did make it work- I think (in my effort to make the post not too long) I made have described the issue wrong.  There are a series of tests at the bottom of the script that our code must pass- the professor then inputs the keys, so it couldn't be specific.  Honestly, it's been a very confusing way to learn for beginners :(.  Any references you could recommend would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ha that does sound confusing! I highly recommend this course for beginners:
https://www.udemy.com/share/101Wg0BkcYcltXQ34=/

I'm not sure how much it is at the moment, I did it ages ago and it had something like 90% off, so was $11 or something. It's excellent for beginners anyway.